# I lost my (Windows 10 Edition) minecraft seed

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My windows 10 edition minecraft world recently got corrupted, but I can't find the original seed. I can get the rest of the world back pretty easily, since it was only the level.dat file that got corrupted, but the seed is stuck in that corrupted file. NBTExplorer doesn't work with windows 10 edition worlds, so I can't use that, and I can't just copy the seed from the last level.dat into a new clean one (it didn't work). Any ideas?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I need the seed so that the level.dat file is from the same generated world, otherwise there will be tons of chunk errors since it's trying to generate the unexplored world from a different seed, and other similar bugs.